# Removing outliers from lists/XY scatter

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two lists containing heart beat intervals (Y-axis, in ms; IBIs below) and their absolute timepoints (X-axis, in ms; RR_times below). There are some misreadings, such that the first list contains outliers that need to be removed, and the second one their corresponding timepoints. It would be optimal if the outliers in the first list are NaN-ed so that the total time for the recording remains the same.

```
 RR_times = [411, 827, 1241,  1653,  2066,   2481,   2894,   3308,
     3714,   4126,   4532,   4938,   5343,   5751,   6156,   6552,
     6951,   7346,   7749,   8149,   8546,   8944,   9338,   9735,
    10123,  10511,  10905,  11290,  11675,  12060,  12441,  12825,
    13205,  13581,  13960,  14342,  14717,  15087,  15462,  15829,
    16204,  16531,  16902,  17304,  17670,  18040,  18398,  18762,
    19127,  19465,  19823,  20196,  20554,  20906,  21256,  21609,
    21959,  22264,  22637,  22995,  23308,  23649,  24012,  24352,
    24687,  25026,  25390,  25681,  26014,  26347,  26680,  27330,
    27985,  28628,  28951,  29596,  29915,  30238,  30562,  31191,
    31826,  32141,  32461,  32775,  33095,  33382,  33695,  34029,
    34341,  34654,  34967,  35281,  35595,  36220,  36530,  36844,
    37150,  37462,  37775,  38084,  38395,  38703,  39014,  39324,
    39632,  39937,  40246,  40554,  40862,  41169,  41479,  41787,
    42095,  42406,  42714,  43019,  43330,  43642,  43945,  44254,
    44563,  44871,  45183,  45491,  45796,  46101,  46410,  46713,
    47327,  47632,  47937,  48244,  48555,  48867,  49177,  49488,
    49792,  50094,  50398,  50707,  50993,  51324,  51626,  51931,
    52239,  52550,  52857,  53161,  53773,  54080,  54387,  54693,
    54998,  55311,  55617,  55924,  56235,  56547,  56852,  57159,
    57470,  57781,  58091,  58400,  58709,  59020,  59331,  59644,
    59955,  60265,  60579,  60890,  61206,  61521,  61833,  62149,
    62463,  62772,  63088,  63403,  63716,  64034,  64352,  64665,
    64984,  65624,  65940,  66262,  66578,  66900,  67221,  67543,
    67861,  68179,  68504,  68819,  69145,  69459,  69782,  70111,
    70428,  70747,  71070,  71389,  71710,  72036,  72358,  72680,
    73003,  73326,  73648,  73973,  74296,  74620,  74944,  75269,
    75592,  75916,  76241,  76566,  76889,  77216,  77543,  77869,
    78191,  78518,  78843,  79165,  79496,  79823,  80148,  80479,
    80803,  81128,  81459,  81783,  82110,  82439,  82771,  83095,
    83426,  83757,  84086,  84416,  84741,  85074,  85400,  85729,
    86060,  86390,  86719,  87051,  87380,  87711,  88041,  88373,
    88705,  89029,  89365,  89698,  90023,  90356,  90690,  91019,
    91352,  91684,  92014,  92347,  92681,  93014,  93349,  93678,
    94011,  94344,  94675,  95009,  95339,  95673,  96007,  96341,
    96668,  97002,  97337,  97665,  98003,  98335,  98668,  99003,
    99339,  99673, 100007, 100346, 100684, 101017, 101357, 101693,
   102028, 102368, 102705, 103043, 103380, 103718, 104061, 104403,
   104736, 105077, 105421, 105756, 106096, 106437, 106777, 107118,
   107461, 107800, 108141, 108485, 108822, 109167, 109507, 109848,
   110196, 110538, 110884, 111230, 111571, 111918, 112263, 112606,
   112952, 113639, 113987, 114336, 114680, 115025, 115372, 115722,
   116068, 116418, 116766, 117114, 117464, 117811, 118158, 118511,
   118858, 119208, 119557, 119904, 120257, 120606, 120952, 121303,
   121655, 122003, 122354, 122707, 123057, 123408, 123760, 124114,
   124466, 124815, 125172, 125523, 125879, 126231, 126586, 126946,
   127298, 127653, 128014, 128369, 128724, 129084, 129441, 129794,
   130150, 130504, 130863, 131219, 131576, 131937, 132297, 132653,
   133012, 133375, 133731, 134091, 134455, 134813, 135174, 135534,
   135897, 136258, 136621, 136986, 137349, 137711, 138073, 138439,
   138799, 139164, 139526, 139887, 140253, 140617, 140977, 141344,
   141706, 142071, 142438, 142803, 143170, 143537, 143904, 144274,
   144641, 145011, 145382, 145749, 146124, 146493, 146864, 147235,
   147605, 147977, 148346, 148718, 149085, 149455, 149826, 150195,
   150566, 150936, 151310, 151676, 152048, 152423, 152795, 153167,
   153539, 153916, 154290, 154661, 155036, 155408, 155782, 156159,
   156530, 156905, 157280, 157655, 158029, 158404, 158783, 159157,
   159532, 159910, 160290, 160660, 161037, 161415, 161786, 162161,
   162538, 162913, 163289, 163665, 164040, 164415, 164789, 165164,
   165539, 165911, 166286, 166661, 167040, 167418, 167791, 168169,
   168545, 168922, 169300, 169676, 170053, 170429, 170811, 171195,
   171571, 171952, 172335, 172717, 173098, 173484, 173869, 174254,
   174637, 175020, 175403, 175785, 176167, 176552, 176933, 177316,
   177698, 178080, 178463, 178840, 179224, 179603, 179979, 180360,
   180739, 181114, 181492, 181870, 182248, 182626, 183001, 183378,
   183752, 184128, 184503, 184876, 185252, 185629, 186003, 186384,
   186760, 187134, 187515, 187900, 188281, 188656, 189031, 189415,
   189798, 190176, 190555, 190936, 191313, 191692, 192069, 192448,
   192824, 193203, 193578, 193953, 194330, 194707]

IBIs = [411,416,414,412,413,415, 413, 414, 406, 412, 406, 406, 405,
   408, 405, 396, 399, 395, 403, 400, 397, 398, 394, 397, 388, 388,
   394, 385, 385, 385, 381, 384, 380, 376, 379, 382, 375, 370, 375,
   367, 375, 327, 371, 402, 366, 370, 358, 364, 365, 338, 358, 373,
   358, 352, 350, 353, 350, 305, 373, 358, 313, 341, 363, 340, 335,
   339, 364, 291, 333, 333, 333, 650, 655, 643, 323, 645, 319, 323,
   324, 629, 635, 315, 320, 314, 320, 287, 313, 334, 312, 313, 313,
   314, 314, 625, 310, 314, 306, 312, 313, 309, 311, 308, 311, 310,
   308, 305, 309, 308, 308, 307, 310, 308, 308, 311, 308, 305, 311,
   312, 303, 309, 309, 308, 312, 308, 305, 305, 309, 303, 614, 305,
   305, 307, 311, 312, 310, 311, 304, 302, 304, 309, 286, 331, 302,
   305, 308, 311, 307, 304, 612, 307, 307, 306, 305, 313, 306, 307,
   311, 312, 305, 307, 311, 311, 310, 309, 309, 311, 311, 313, 311,
   310, 314, 311, 316, 315, 312, 316, 314, 309, 316, 315, 313, 318,
   318, 313, 319, 640, 316, 322, 316, 322, 321, 322, 318, 318, 325,
   315, 326, 314, 323, 329, 317, 319, 323, 319, 321, 326, 322, 322,
   323, 323, 322, 325, 323, 324, 324, 325, 323, 324, 325, 325, 323,
   327, 327, 326, 322, 327, 325, 322, 331, 327, 325, 331, 324, 325,
   331, 324, 327, 329, 332, 324, 331, 331, 329, 330, 325, 333, 326,
   329, 331, 330, 329, 332, 329, 331, 330, 332, 332, 324, 336, 333,
   325, 333, 334, 329, 333, 332, 330, 333, 334, 333, 335, 329, 333,
   333, 331, 334, 330, 334, 334, 334, 327, 334, 335, 328, 338, 332,
   333, 335, 336, 334, 334, 339, 338, 333, 340, 336, 335, 340, 337,
   338, 337, 338, 343, 342, 333, 341, 344, 335, 340, 341, 340, 341,
   343, 339, 341, 344, 337, 345, 340, 341, 348, 342, 346, 346, 341,
   347, 345, 343, 346, 687, 348, 349, 344, 345, 347, 350, 346, 350,
   348, 348, 350, 347, 347, 353, 347, 350, 349, 347, 353, 349, 346,
   351, 352, 348, 351, 353, 350, 351, 352, 354, 352, 349, 357, 351,
   356, 352, 355, 360, 352, 355, 361, 355, 355, 360, 357, 353, 356,
   354, 359, 356, 357, 361, 360, 356, 359, 363, 356, 360, 364, 358,
   361, 360, 363, 361, 363, 365, 363, 362, 362, 366, 360, 365, 362,
   361, 366, 364, 360, 367, 362, 365, 367, 365, 367, 367, 367, 370,
   367, 370, 371, 367, 375, 369, 371, 371, 370, 372, 369, 372, 367,
   370, 371, 369, 371, 370, 374, 366, 372, 375, 372, 372, 372, 377,
   374, 371, 375, 372, 374, 377, 371, 375, 375, 375, 374, 375, 379,
   374, 375, 378, 380, 370, 377, 378, 371, 375, 377, 375, 376, 376,
   375, 375, 374, 375, 375, 372, 375, 375, 379, 378, 373, 378, 376,
   377, 378, 376, 377, 376, 382, 384, 376, 381, 383, 382, 381, 386,
   385, 385, 383, 383, 383, 382, 382, 385, 381, 383, 382, 382, 383,
   377, 384, 379, 376, 381, 379, 375, 378, 378, 378, 378, 375, 377,
   374, 376, 375, 373, 376, 377, 374, 381, 376, 374, 381, 385, 381,
   375, 375, 384, 383, 378, 379, 381, 377, 379, 377, 379, 376, 379,
   375, 375, 377, 377]
```

Plotting the whole dataset gives: [image: heart-rate data plotted against time]

I previously used an above:below-filter, but that does not work for longer recordings in which the trace spans across larger values (in some recordings the intervals span from 300 (during training) to 1500 (after a period of resting).

What is the best way to remove the outliers in this case, and how would one go about implementing it? Moving average, exclusion based on stdev, median filter...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a ugly approach that seems to work:

```
import numpy as np
RR_times = np.array([411, 827, 1241, ...])
IBIs = np.array([411, 416, 414, ...])
diffs = [np.abs(IBIs[i]-IBIs[i+1]) for i in range(len(IBIs)-1)]
IBIs_cleaned = np.full(IBIs.shape, np.nan) # create a array full of NaNs
IBIs_cleaned[0] = IBIs[0] # The first value isn't a outlier

for i in range(1, len(IBIs)):
    if np.abs(IBIs[i]-IBIs[i-1]) < np.mean(diffs) and IBIs[i] < 1.6 * np.mean(IBIs):
        IBIs_cleaned[i] = IBIs[i]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, this approach wouldn't work for the smaller artefacts in the beginning of the recording, or for recordings where the trace goes from for example 300ms to 1500ms since the absolute values of the artefacts would be smaller or larger than parts of the trace. In that case one would have to apply a moving average and apply the StDev-exclusion based on a neighbouring segment of data for each data-point. Also, I've added the raw data.

Comment: The update is really neat. It works nicely, and also allows for the parameters of filtration to be changed according to needs.